# I want a float value - Nan to give the float value and not nan

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pivot-table

I wanted find the difference between two dataframes but the index values of both the dataframes are different. So when I take the difference, I get Nan for the index rows that are not in both the dataframes.

for example df1 has rows A B C and df2 has rows A B D. when I take df=df1-df2

df1 is
[image: df1]

df2 is
[image: df2]

The output of df=df1-df2 that I get is

[image: output that I get]

The output I want is

[image: output I want]

I actually don't know what to do. Should I loop through each value and check is they are nan?